# Filtering data in R (V1 to V250)

Tags: r

I have a data set with columns that are name V1 to V250. Out of all the numeric observations, i need to filter the columns such that

- From column V1 to V30, i need to filter only missing values cells
- From column V31 to V60, i need to filter out all values that are not between 0 and 1
- From column V61 to V90, i need to filter out all values that are not between 0 and positive infinite
- From column V91 to V120, i need to filter out all values that are NOT between negative ifinite and 0
- From  column V121 to v150, i need to filter all values that are not betweem 0 and 300
- From column V151 to V250, i need to filter only missing values cells

I tried some coding with the filter function, but it seems like many observations are either being cut out when they should be kept in the database or data that should be cut, such as missing values, stay in the database.

Tried using filter function, but did not work.

Comment: If your data set is a table, such as a data.frame or a tibble, the result will most likely not be in tabular form. Is this what you want?

Comment: I just want to take off the values from the table that I do not want, such as values that are not between 0 and 300 in columns V121 and V150

Comment: @UmbertoDevezaMalanga are you using/familiar with `tidyverse`?

Comment: yesssssssssssss

Comment: @UmbertoDevezaMalanga are you able to do dput(head(df)) and add it to your question? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Given you are familiar with `tidyverse`, let me say two things: (1) without providing us at least a `dput()` of your data you've left us in a difficult position from which to determine why `filter()` did not work in your code. In future, please know it's much easier to receive help on SO if you provide data.

(2) my advice is that you pipe multiple filters to achieve your desired outcome. For example:

```
your_data.set %>%
  filter_at(vars(V1:V30),all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
etc...
```

Or, to filter `NA`s from a single column:

```
your_data.set %>%
   filter(V1 != 'na') %>% 
etc.
```

Please note: I'm assuming that "missing values" means NA in your df.

And just to add: the `all_vars(!is.na(.))` means that your listed variables **must** be something other than NA.

If this works, please kindly "accept" my answer (this is how SO works). If not, please further clarify and I'll take another shot. Thanks!

Comment: Just following up, @Umberto Deveza Malanga--did this solution work for you? Cheers!